# Where am I going wrong with this topojson makefile?

Tags: makefile, topojson

I have tried the following two instructions in my makefile:

```
states_topojson.json: states.shp
    node_modules/.bin/topojson \
        -o $@ 

states_topojson.json: states.shp
        node_modules/.bin/topojson \
            -o $@ 
        --projection='width = 960, height = 600, d3.geo.albersUsa() \
            .scale(1280) \
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2])' \
        --simplify=.5 \
        --filter=none \
```

I am able to make other files, so I know topojson is correctly installed with node.

My states.shp file is straight from the Bostock Us-Atlas and was made with:

```
make shp/us/states-unfiltered.shp
```

[Seen here](https://github.com/mbostock/us-atlas/blob/master/Makefile)

When I try and run:

```
topojson -o output.json states.shp
```

I get this noise:

```
Trace: { [Error: ENOENT, open 'states.dbf'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'states.dbf' }
    at output (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/bin/topojson:259:29)
    at notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/queue-async/queue.js:45:26)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/queue-async/queue.js:35:11
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/bin/topojson:236:23
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/shapefile/index.js:14:23
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/shapefile/read.js:26:29
    at notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/queue-async/queue.js:45:26)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/queue-async/queue.js:35:11
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/shapefile/index.js:45:25
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/shapefile/dbf.js:16:30
```

Moving the .dbf file to the root folder made the topojson command line work. But the makefile still fails.

Comment: Does the *makefile* fail, or does the command `topojson -o output.json states.shp` fail? I assume you're trying the command without Make. (If you're not, please do so and don't bring the makefile into this.)

Comment: @Beta The makefile hangs. The command succeeds.

Comment: All right, is that the command you want Make to execute? If so, then write a rule in the makefile that will execute that command; if not, try the command you want Make to execute.

Comment: @Beta The make is at top.

Answer (score 1):

This may take a few iterations.

Try this makefile (Make is a tool; a makefile is a file which Make reads, a kind of script):

```
output.json:
    topojson -o output.json states.shp
```

Tell us whether it works, and we can proceed.

Comment: That command works (I mention so in my edit). It's the makefile at the top that isn't working.

Comment: @Incodeveritas: You are using the terms **"command"** and **"makefile"** interchangeably. That is part of the problem. Do you want a makefile that works, or do you want to know why your first makefile doesn't work?

Comment: Command here means command line -- there's a topojson command line tool.